# yii2 basic printing a page in pdf

Tags: yii2

please help. 
Hallo all, Am on verge of finishing a project created using yii2 basic. my problem is, I want to print a using with pdf as its output. I have tried yii2 mpdf and yii2-pdf without any success. I want to place the print button in the index.php of a view file. here's is my code snippet located at index view file.

```
<?= Html::a('<i class="fa glyphicon glyphicon-hand-up"></i>Property report',['/propertydetails/report'],
        [
         'class'=>'btn btn-danger',
         'target'=> '_blank',
         'data-toggle'=>'tooltip',
         'title'=>'Generate the pdf']); ?>
```

And here's my controller

```
use kartik\mpdf\Pdf;

//function for reports
public function actionReport()
{
    //get your html raw content without layouts
   // $content = $this->renderPartial('view');
    //set up the kartik\mpdf\Pdf component
    $pdf = new Pdf([
        'content'=>$this->renderPartial('view'),
        'mode'=> Pdf::MODE_CORE,
        'format'=> Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
        'orientation'=>Pdf::ORIENT_POTRAIT,
        'destination'=> Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
        'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
        'cssInline'=> '.kv-heading-1{font-size:18px}',
        'options'=> ['title'=> 'Paki Properties Reports'],
        'methods'=> [
               'setHeader'=>['Generated on: '.date("r")],
               'setFooter'=>['|page {PAGENO}|'],
                ]
        ]);
    return $pdf->render();
}
```

when I click the button I get this error

```
 PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException
```

Undefined variable: model

```
1. in C:\wamp\www\pakiSystems1\views\propertydetails\view.php at line 9
123456789101112131415161718

<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\DetailView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $model app\models\Propertydetails */

$this->title = $model->propertyId;
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => 'Propertydetails', 'url' => ['index']];
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="propertydetails-view">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <p>
        <?= Html::a('Update', ['update', 'id' => $model->propertyId], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>

2. in C:\wamp\www\pakiSystems1\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\View.php – yii\base\View::renderPhpFile() at line 247
3. in C:\wamp\www\pakiSystems1\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\View.php – yii\base\View::renderFile() at line 149
4. in C:\wamp\www\pakiSystems1\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php – yii\base\View::render() at line 398
5. in C:\wamp\www\pakiSystems1\controllers\PropertydetailsController.php – yii\base\Controller::renderPartial() at line 77
71727374757677787980818283

    public function actionReport()
    {
        //get your html raw content without layouts
       // $content = $this->renderPartial('view');
        //set up the kartik\mpdf\Pdf component
        $pdf = new Pdf([
            'content'=>$this->renderPartial('view'),
            'mode'=> Pdf::MODE_CORE,
            'format'=> Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
            'orientation'=>Pdf::ORIENT_POTRAIT,
            'destination'=> Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
            'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
            'cssInline'=> '.kv-heading-1{font-size:18px}',
```

any help I will highly appreciate. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

In your controller there isn't the model. 
You must add this information eg:

```
$content = $this->renderPartial('_mpdf_report_scheda',  [
     'model' => $model,

     'mode'=> Pdf::MODE_CORE,
     'format'=> Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
     'orientation'=>Pdf::ORIENT_POTRAIT,
     'destination'=> Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
     .....
           ]);
```

Comment: It worked. :) Thanks very much. I really appreciate. If I may ask why is Pdf::ORIENT_POTRAIT not working?

Comment: In don't know for me work correct. I invite you to make another question in StackOverflow. In this way more people can see your question and could help you. New questions are read more then olds.

Comment: there's another slight problem. when it converts to pdf,it's not the current page that is converted but the one in renderPartial('index', 'searchModel'=>$searchModel). How can I can I print the current page being displayed?? Thanks again for your time

Comment: The data used in the page converted in PDF iarev the data in  `$model` at the moment  you call the renderPartial. If you need the data of the actual page ( i guess the page you are seeing when you call the print of PDF) you must assigne at $model the correct instance of the data.

Comment: .Ok. Now that correct instance is what I cant be able to use.