# Undefined Variable model in kartik mpdf - yii2

Tags: yii2

I'm trying to use kartik mpdf to print data to a pdf file. I'm facing kind of same problem as - [yii2 basic printing a page in pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30434175/yii2-basic-printing-a-page-in-pdf).
I've tried the solution given there but still getting the error.
View file(the code for the button) -

```
<?= Html::a('<i class="fa glyphicon glyphicon-print"></i> Print Salary Statement', ['/salary/salary/printsalarystatement'], [
            'class'=>'btn btn-primary', 
            'target'=>'_blank', 
            'data-toggle'=>'tooltip', 
            'title'=>'Will open the generated PDF file in a new window'
        ]);?>
```

Controller

```
public function actionPrintsalarystatement() {

        $pdf = new Pdf([
        'content'=>$this->renderPartial('_printSalarystatement'), [
            'model'=> $model,
            'mode'=> Pdf::MODE_CORE,
            'format'=> Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
            'orientation'=>Pdf::ORIENT_POTRAIT,
            'destination'=> Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
            'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
            'cssInline'=> '.kv-heading-1{font-size:18px}',
            'options'=> ['title'=> 'Salary Statement'],
            'methods'=> [
                   'setHeader'=>['Generated on: '.date("r")],
                   'setFooter'=>['|page {PAGENO}|'],
                    ]
            ],

        ]);
        return $pdf->render();
    }
```

Present View.php -

```
<?= Html::a('<i class="fa glyphicon glyphicon-print"></i> Print Salary Statement', ['/salary/salary/printsalarystatement?id=s_id'], [
            'class'=>'btn btn-primary', 
            'target'=>'_blank', 
            'data-toggle'=>'tooltip', 
            'title'=>'Will open the generated PDF file in a new window'
        ]);?>
```

Present Controller

```
public function actionPrintsalarystatement($id) {

        //$model =  Salary::find()->where(['s_id' => $id]);
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        $searchModel  = new SalarySearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
        $data         = Salary::findOne($id);
        $content = $this->renderPartial('_printSalarystatement', ['model' => $model,'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,'searchModel'  => $searchModel,'data'=> $data]);
        $pdf = new Pdf([
            'mode'=> Pdf::MODE_CORE,
            'format'=> Pdf::FORMAT_A4,
            'destination'=> Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
            'content'     => $content,

        ]);
        return $pdf->render();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you generating the `$model`? You need to pass or call that into the function somehow.

Comment: I'm not so sure what you are talking about. There is 'model' => $model, below 'content'=>$this->renderPartial('_printSalarystatement'). Please tell me what modification needds to be done.

Comment: I can't really tell you what needs to be done without seeing more of the code. What I'm asking is where are you defining that `$model` variable? I.e., where is the data populating `_printSalarystatement` coming from?

Comment: _printSalarystatement is a simple copy of the 'view' file. The data is coming from Model Salary. Let me know what code you want?

Comment: try fetching the Salary model (create `$model`) inside this action.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function actionPrintsalarystatement() {

     // you don't have the model for passing to the pdf object  
     // eg: 
      $model =  YourModel::find()->where(['your_column' => 'your_value']);


     $pdf = new Pdf([
      'content'=>$this->renderPartial('_printSalarystatement'), [
        'model'=> $model, // this $model is missing if you don assign a proper result to the this var like suggested above
        'mode'=> Pdf::MODE_CORE,
```

Based on your comment :

1. you don'have a proper $id so you can't retrieve nothings
2. you have  `$model = Salary::find()->where(['s_id' => '$id']);`   this is wrong you must remove  the quotes around $id this way    `$model = Salary::find()->where(['s_id' => $id]);`

If you have $id in the page where you call the actionPrintsalarystatement tye you could pass to the action

eg:

```
  /salary/salary/printsalarystatement?id=your_id
```

and

```
   public function actionPrintsalarystatement($id) {
```

Comment: I've added $model =  Salary::find()->where(['s_id' => '$id']); as I got. But it's throwing the error - Setting unknown property: kartik\mpdf\Pdf::0

Comment: @Tanmay   i have update the answer with some suggestio based on your comment

Comment: Now I'm getting Undefined variable: id. Please help.

Comment: You're trying to print something in pdf .. to perform this task you need to assign the call PDF a proper data model that should be assigned to the variable $ model .. Well which is the data model you want to go to pdf and how you are able to get it .. try to show me the related  code ..

Comment: As per my understanding the button in the view file is calling actionPrintsalarystatement(). In this controller I have the code you already know. In that code there is a line - $model =  Salary::find()->where(['s_id' => $id]); I think the controller is finding the model by this line. According to you "don't have a proper $id so you can't retrieve nothings". I'm not so sure how to do this. Please let me know which piece of code you want me to share. I'll do.

Comment: If you want retrieve the Salary model where s_id is equal to $id then you should have $id  somewhere  .. you should pass this $id in function call like a parameter  .. i .. have update the answer  -hope is clear ..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116934/discussion-between-tanmay-and-scaisedge).

Comment: I found similar solution made by you here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36502971/yii2-how-to-add-model-and-model-id-in-mpdf. I'm trying to do the same thing and my Controller and view I've given seperately in present Controller and present view in the question. The question is same. But I'm facing error - Page not found. Please help.

Comment: Page not found when happend .. ?

Comment: Hi ScaiseEdge. I've found the solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36502971/yii2-how-to-add-model-and-model-id-in-mpdf. Thank you very much.

Comment: i hope that my answer (this or the one in you comment)  and or my comments are useful for you ..and you rate properly the  useful contributions ..